# Can't create child contract in mainnet?

Tags: solidity, tokens, dapps, factory

```
address[] child;

function createChildContract() onlyOwner public{
    address newChild = new Child(msg.sender);
    child.push(newChild);
    emit ChildCreated(newChild);
}

contract Child {
   address public owner;

constructor(address _owner) public{
    owner = _owner;
}

function getOwner() external view returns(address){
    return owner;
}
```

I can make child contracts with this code in testnet but in mainnet it dosen't work.

Does mainnet just impossible to create child contract? or my code is wrong?

Comment: You didn't paste all the code.

Comment: What is the error you get in mainnet?

Comment: There is no errors
https://etherscan.io/address/0x486f7112a03e622af4619732a20b07b12a003159
transaction is success but there is no event and child variable is empty
@LauriPeltonen

Comment: @PeterPrographo Sorry im new here i don't know how to paste code

Comment: None of your mainnet transaction contain any data (except contract creation). You are calling the contract wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your transactions to the contract show that you aren't including any tx data, meaning you aren't calling `createChildContract`.